# Data from Access will not copy to Word bookmark

Tags: ms-access

I have data from a query name "GrabInfoOfMostRecent" and I am using it as a source for Word to fill in a document with bookmarks. However, once I get to any non-text data, I get error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Specifically:

1. For "MRN"I have tried all variations of .Range.Text/Value/Value2 and cannot get the number MRN to fill into the appropriate Bookmark.
2. For "Diagnosis1", I get an Error13 "Type Mismatch" but I don't know why. It is defined as "Short Text" just as all previous text entries are.

Anyone with any help, I would be deeply appreciative.

```vb
Sub WordAutomation()
On Error GoTo HandleError

' Object variables for Automation stuff
' declare them like so during development
' you need to set a reference to the applications
'Dim objWord As New Word.Application
' declare them like this when development is complete
' references no longer necessary

Dim objWord As Object

' Object variables for database access
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rstPatientVisit As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsReportData As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsExclusions As DAO.Recordset

' Scalar variables
Dim strsql As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim conPath As String
Dim wdGoToBookmark As Integer

'find the folder where the database resides
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsReportData = db.OpenRecordset("GrabInfoOfMostRecent")


strFile = db.Name
conPath = Mid(strFile, 1, Len(strFile) - Len(Dir(strFile)))

'Step through the records one at a time, creating a Word
'document for each.
'Do While Not rsReportData.EOF

'--create new word document
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Documents.Add conPath & "TunTemplate.dotx"

' Make both Word and the document are visible
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Windows(1).Visible = True

'find bookmarks and insert values
With objWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
    .Item("RDFirst").Range.Text = rsReportData!RDFirstName
    .Item("RDLast").Range.Text = rsReportData!RDLastName
    .Item("PFirstName").Range.Text = rsReportData!PVFirstName
    .Item("PLastName").Range.Text = rsReportData!PVLastName
    .Item("MRN").Range.Value2 = rsReportData!MRN
    .Item("RDAddress").Range.Text = rsReportData!RDAddress
    .Item("PAddress").Range.Text = rsReportData!Address
    .Item("RDCity").Range.Text = rsReportData!RDCity
    .Item("RDCounty").Range.Text = rsReportData!RDCounty
    .Item("PCity").Range.Text = rsReportData!City
    .Item("PCounty").Range.Text = rsReportData!County
    .Item("RDPostalCode").Range.Text = rsReportData!RDPostalCode
    .Item("PPostalCode").Range.Text = rsReportData!PostalCode
    .Item("Diagnosis1").Range.Text = rsReportData!Diagnosis1
    .Item("Treatment1").Range.Text = rsReportData!Treatment1
    .Item("Changes1").Range.Text = rsReportData!Changes1
    .Item("Diagnosis2").Range.Text = rsReportData!Diagnosis2
    .Item("Treatment2").Range.Text = rsReportData!Treatment2
    .Item("Changes2").Range.Text = rsReportData!Changes2
    .Item("Diagnosis3").Range.Text = rsReportData!Diagnosis3
    .Item("Treatment3").Range.Text = rsReportData!Treatment3
    .Item("Changes3").Range.Text = rsReportData!Changes3
    .Item("Diagnosis4").Range.Text = rsReportData!Diagnosis4
    .Item("Treatment4").Range.Text = rsReportData!Treatment4
    .Item("Changes4").Range.Text = rsReportData!Changes4
    .Item("Diagnosis5").Range.Text = rsReportData!Diagnosis5
    .Item("Treatment5").Range.Text = rsReportData!Treatment5
    .Item("Changes5").Range.Text = rsReportData!Changes5
    .Item("Weight").Range.Text = rsReportData!Weight
    .Item("Height").Range.Text = rsReportData!Height
    .Item("BMICalc").Range.Text = rsReportData!BMICalc
    .Item("Waist").Range.Text = rsReportData!Waist
    .Item("BP").Range.Text = rsReportData!BP
    .Item("RAcuity").Range.Text = rsReportData!REyeAcuity
    .Item("LAcuity").Range.Text = rsReportData!LEyeAcuity
    .Item("RRetina").Range.Text = rsReportData!RLensRetina
    .Item("LRetina").Range.Text = rsReportData!LLensRetina
    .Item("HbA1c").Range.Text = rsReportData!HbA1C
    .Item("Creatinine").Range.Text = rsReportData!Creatinine
    .Item("TChol").Range.Text = rsReportData!TChol
    .Item("UrineACR").Range.Text = rsReportData!UrineACR
    .Item("LDL").Range.Text = rsReportData!LDL
    .Item("TSH").Range.Text = rsReportData!TSH
    .Item("HDL").Range.Text = rsReportData!HDL
    .Item("B12").Range.Text = rsReportData!B12
    .Item("TG").Range.Text = rsReportData!TG
    .Item("EGFR").Range.Text = rsReportData!EGFR
End With

'find and write exclusion data
strsql = "SELECT ReportID, Exclusion " & _
    "FROM ExclusionData " & _
    "WHERE ReportID=" & rsReportData!ReportID

Set rsExclusions = db.OpenRecordset(strsql)
    Do While Not rsExclusions.EOF
    With objWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        .Item("exclusions").Range.Text = rsExclusions!Exclusion & vbCrLf
        rsExclusions.MoveNext
    End With
Loop
rsExclusions.Close


'Save the document and close Word
objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs (conPath & rsReportData!MRN & ".doc")
'objWord.Quit

'go to next record for processing
'rsReportData.MoveNext
'Loop


'Tell the user the process is done.
MsgBox "Done!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
"Look in this directory" & vbCrLf & conPath & vbCrLf & _
"for your documents."

ProcDone:

' clean up our object variables
Set objWord = Nothing
Set rsReportData = Nothing
Set rsExclusions = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

ExitHere:
Exit Sub
HandleError:
'display appropriate error message
Select Case Err.Number
    Case 5151 'Word template not found
        'Close stranded applications
        MsgBox "Word template not found"
    Case 5152 'Invalid file name
        'Close stranded applications
        objWord.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False
        objWord.Quit
        MsgBox "This file or folder does not exist"
    Case Else
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, _
         "Error " & Err.Number
End Select
Resume ProcDone
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply with the desire to help you troubleshoot this; I offer the following.

Try converting the problem field into a string using:

```
.Item("Diagnosis1").Range.Text = CStr(rsReportData!Diagnosis1)
```

You may also want to display a dialog box with the contents of `rsReportData!Diagnosis1`:

```
MsgBox "rsReportData!Diagnosis1 is: " & rsReportData!Diagnosis1 _
    , vbOkOnly + vbInformation
```

To convert null values into zero-length-strings, you can use the following:

```
.Item("Diagnosis1").Range.Text= IIf(IsNull(rsReportData!Diagnosis1), "", rsReportData!Diagnosis1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! What I have figured out is that for some reason, when Diagnosis1 is empty, it throws an error (Error 94 Invalid use of Null). But when I assign a value to Diagnosis1 (e.g. "chicken"), it has no problem. Now I just have to figure out why this is happening! Any thoughts?

Comment: That's probably because the value is NULL which cannot "assigned" as text to the bookmark.  You'll likely need to use IsNull or something similar to convert nulls to zero-length-strings.

Comment: OKay, thanks so much, I'll figure out how to do that now and it in!